# Scrollview Content not updating

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiscrollviewdelegate

AM facing trouble in showing Images on the ImageView, added on UIScrollview, after rotation

I am having few UIImageViews(8 diferent) on my UIScrollView.

The Problem, is when I rotate my Device, **I have changed the frame(x,y axis only) of UIscrollview** and of (x,y axis only) 
, It doesn't displays the Images, I added on the UIimageViews after Rotation.

**After Rotation, I touched the ScrollView, and then It shows the Images on the Uiimageviews again.** I tried everything. Surfed Stackoverflow and google, found nothing, working in my case.

```
//Magazine Images
        //subview1 MAG Imaegs
        [[asy_Array_Mag_sub1 objectAtIndex:0] setFrame:CGRectMake(59, 120, 136, 174)];
        [[asy_Array_Mag_sub1 objectAtIndex:1] setFrame:CGRectMake(296, 120, 136, 174)];
        [[asy_Array_Mag_sub1 objectAtIndex:2] setFrame:CGRectMake(576, 120, 136, 174)];
        [[asy_Array_Mag_sub1 objectAtIndex:3] setFrame:CGRectMake(802, 176, 136, 174)];
        [[asy_Array_Mag_sub1 objectAtIndex:4] setFrame:CGRectMake(57, 465, 136, 174)];
        [[asy_Array_Mag_sub1 objectAtIndex:5] setFrame:CGRectMake(296, 383, 136, 174)];
        [[asy_Array_Mag_sub1 objectAtIndex:6] setFrame:CGRectMake(570, 377, 136, 174)];
        [[asy_Array_Mag_sub1 objectAtIndex:7] setFrame:CGRectMake(802, 486, 136, 174)];


        [self.otlScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,  1024, 768)];

        self.otlScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1024 * total_pages, 768);



        [_otlSubView setFrame:CGRectMake(a1, 0, 1024, 768)];
        [self.otlScrollView addSubview:_otlSubView];
        [_otlSubView2 setFrame:CGRectMake(b1, 0, 1024, 768)];
        [self.otlScrollView addSubview:_otlSubView2];
        [_otlSubView3 setFrame:CGRectMake(c1, 0, 1024, 768)];
        [self.otlScrollView addSubview:_otlSubView3];





        [_otlScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(1024 * (self.otlPageControl.currentPage), 0)];
```

Comment: Dont post duplicate of your question, add a bounty for your question or edit your question: [Content of UIscrollview not updating, when changing orientation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21859624/content-of-uiscrollview-not-updating-when-changing-orientation)

Comment: @rckoenes
OK, will keep thing in mind. Do you know, why am facing this problem?
Is there any thing I missed?

Comment: @Jeev can u add some code

Comment: @Nassif I have edited the question, by adding code. Please have a look

Comment: @Jeev the frames are not proper also are u adding these images to the scrollview,if u are looking for a grid type ,i would suggest you better go for uicollectionview.

Comment: @Nassif But My compenets are placed at different places. Collection view doesn't provide that much flexibilty and I have IMplemented 100% of the UI, at this point

Comment: @Jeev [asy_Array_Mag_sub1 objectAtIndex:0]  is it uiimageview

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47851/discussion-between-jeev-and-nassif)